# MATLAB's glmfit vs fitglm

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-mining, glm, logistic-regression

I'm trying to perform logistic regression to do classification using MATLAB. There seem to be two different methods in MATLAB's statistics toolbox to build a generalized linear model 'glmfit' and 'fitglm'. I can't figure out what the difference is between the two. Is one preferable over the other?

Here are the links for the function descriptions.

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitglm.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is what the functions output. `glmfit` just outputs **a vector** of the regression coefficients (and some other stuff if you ask for it). `fitglm` outputs a regression **object** that packs all sorts of information and functionality inside (See the docs on [GeneralizedLinearModel class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalizedlinearmodel-class.html)). I would assume the `fitglm` is intended to replace `glmfit`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Dan's answer, I would like to add the following.

The function `fitglm`, like newer functions from the statistics toolbox, accepts more flexible inputs than `glmfit`. For example, you can use a table as the data source, specifyy a formula of the form `Y ~ X1 + X2 + ...`, and use categorical variables.

As a side note, the function `lassoglm` uses (depends on) `glmfit`.